# Android RecyclerView Java

Tags: java, android

I am trying to understand this concept for a while now. Can someone please help me? RecyclerView.ViewHolder and RecyclerView.Adapter The .ViewHolder and .Adapter. Is it a inner class concept from Java or something else. I am trying to connect dots here.

Comment: Yes, they are both static inner classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are static [nested classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html).

You can reference them using:

```
OuterClass.StaticNestedClass nestedObject =
     new OuterClass.StaticNestedClass();
```

The inner classes are not static and are associated with an instance of its enclosing class:

```
OuterClass outerObject = new OuterClass()
OuterClass.InnerClass innerObject = outerObject.new InnerClass();
```

Comment: Gabriele. Thanks a bunch for clearing that.